# Serialising an object(s) to a file and reading back the list of

Tags: vb.net, serialization

in my vb.net app I serialise an object to a file. I do this every now and again.
I close my app
I start my app and I try/want to read the list of objects I have written but it does not work.

This is my model:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class test
    Public FontColor As Color = Color.Black
    Public Contrast As Int32 = 0
    Public Text As String = ""
End Class
```

This is how I write to my file:

```
Dim formatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
Dim stream As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\testme.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
Dim TextValues As New test
TextValues.Contrast = 10
TextValues.FontColor = Color.AliceBlue
TextValues.Text = "hello andy"

formatter.Serialize(stream, TextValues)
stream.Close()
```

NB, yes I know I should be using the keyword 'Using' :)

This is how I read it back in:

```
Dim formatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
Dim stream As New FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\testme.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)

REM THIS WORKS OK BUT FOR ONLY 1 OBJECT ******************************
Dim TextValues = CType(formatter.Deserialize(stream), test)
REM *********************************************************************

REM ***THIS JUST ERRORS *************************************************
Dim TextValues2 = CType(formatter.Deserialize(stream), List(Of test))
REM *********************************************************************

stream.Close()
```

Comment: You only serialize a single object, to serialize a list you must first create a list.

Comment: Dont try to append to a serialized file.  It can be done, but its a mess because the BinaryFormatter will add type info before each new addition, then to read #3 you still have to read 1 and 2 first - it wont be random access.  Create a collection and write them all at once.  Read them back the same way.

Comment: @VisualVincent yes, the conclusion I came to myself :)

Comment: @Plutonix understood. Best not to do it then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List(Of TextValue)` and serialize/deserialize that if you want to write and read multiple `TextValue` objects.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for the Edit, I think in C# most of the time.

Comment: Same goes for me and VB.NET. :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But it has to be added to the file 1 at a time :(

Comment: @AndrewSimpson If your file is small enough, you can just deserialize, add the item to the resulting list, then reserialize.  If your file is too large, then you probably will start needing to think outside the standard serialization methods and go custom.